# How to format structure of json to meet another structure

Tags: php, json, laravel

Hello I have a json response I have derived from an uploaded excel sheet below.

The reason for this task is upload an excel sheet, copy its contents, convert to json and  then select a required few columns to be posted to a 3rd party platform

The below json output comes from a variable $data

```
[
1,
{
    "1": {
        "A": "ean",
        "B": "sku",
        "C": "tenant-ecommerce",
        "D": "brand-ecommerce",
        "E": "season-ecommerce",
        "F": "gender-ecommerce",
        "G": "age_group-ecommerce",
        "H": "family",
        "I": "parent",
        "J": "sku_config",
        "K": "name-ecommerce",
        "L": "style_name-ecommerce",
        "M": "ay_name",
        "N": "producttyp-ecommerce",
        "O": "master_color-ecommerce",
        "P": "color",
        "Q": "master_size",
        "R": "eu_size",
        "S": "size_grid-ecommerce",
        "T": "selling_price-ecommerce-EUR",
        "U": "selling_price_old-ecommerce-EUR",
        "V": "purchase_price-ecommerce-EUR",
        "W": "rrp-ecommerce-EUR",
        "X": "description-ecommerce",
        "Y": "bullet_point01-ecommerce",
        "Z": "bullet_point02-ecommerce",
        "AA": "bullet_point03-ecommerce",
        "AB": "bullet_point04-ecommerce",
        "AC": "bullet_point05-ecommerce",
        "AD": "keywords-ecommerce",
        "AE": "main_image",
        "AF": "image_01-ecommerce",
        "AG": "image_02-ecommerce",
        "AH": "image_03-ecommerce",
        "AI": "image_04-ecommerce",
        "AJ": "image_05-ecommerce",
        "AK": "image_06-ecommerce",
        "AL": "image_07-ecommerce",
        "AM": "image_08-ecommerce",
        "AN": "image_09-ecommerce",
        "AO": "image_10-ecommerce",
        "AP": "image_11-ecommerce",
        "AQ": "image_12-ecommerce",
        "AR": "image_01_3x4",
        "AS": "image_02_3x4",
        "AT": "image_03_3x4",
        "AU": "image_04_3x4",
        "AV": "image_05_3x4",
        "AW": "image_06_3x4",
        "AX": "image_07_3x4",
        "AY": "image_08_3x4",
        "AZ": "image_09_3x4",
        "BA": "image_10_3x4",
        "BB": "image_11_3x4",
        "BC": "image_12_3x4",
        "BD": "image_13_3x4",
        "BE": "image_14_3x4",
        "BF": "material-ecommerce",
        "BG": "upper_material-ecommerce",
        "BH": "inner_material-ecommerce",
        "BI": "ingredients-ecommerce",
        "BJ": "wash-ecommerce",
        "BK": "tumble-ecommerce",
        "BL": "chemical_clean-ecommerce",
        "BM": "bleach-ecommerce",
        "BN": "iron-ecommerce",
        "BO": "function-ecommerce",
        "BP": "packaging-ecommerce",
        "BQ": "set",
        "BR": "technologies-de_DE-ecommerce",
        "BS": "hazard_warning-ecommerce",
        "BT": "safety_instructions-ecommerce",
        "BU": "signal_word-ecommerce",
        "BV": "width-de_DE",
        "BW": "width-de_DE-unit",
        "BX": "length-de_DE",
        "BY": "length-de_DE-unit",
        "BZ": "pattern-ecommerce",
        "CA": "items_delivered-ecommerce",
        "CB": "shoe_tip-ecommerce",
        "CC": "special_features-ecommerce",
        "CD": "model_size-ecommerce",
        "CE": "Size_indication-ecommerce",
        "CF": "country_of_manufacture-ecommerce",
        "CG": "manufacturer_no-ecommerce",
        "CH": "VAT_Type-ecommerce",
        "CI": "delivery_depth-de_DE",
        "CJ": "delivery_depth-de_DE-unit",
        "CK": "delivery_length-de_DE",
        "CL": "delivery_length-de_DE-unit",
        "CM": "delivery_width-de_DE",
        "CN": "delivery_width-de_DE-unit",
        "CO": "weight-de_DE",
        "CP": "weight-de_DE-unit",
        "CQ": "tariff_number-ecommerce",
        "CR": "sustainability",
        "CS": "bluesign",
        "CT": "CmiA",
        "CU": "c2c",
        "CV": "fairtrade_cotton",
        "CW": "FSC",
        "CX": "FWF",
        "CY": "GOTS",
        "CZ": "GRS",
        "DA": "gruener_knopf",
        "DB": "OCS",
        "DC": "dermatologically_approved",
        "DD": "oekotex_green",
        "DE": "oeco_tex_100",
        "DF": "organic_cotton",
        "DG": "PAV",
        "DH": "recycled_polyester",
        "DI": "vegan",
        "DJ": "criteria_eco-ecommerce",
        "DK": "criteria_recycled-ecommerce",
        "DL": "criteria_vegan-ecommerce",
        "DM": "criteria_durable-ecommerce",
        "DN": "criteria_co2_neutral-ecommerce",
        "DO": "criteria_cradle_to_cradle-ecommerce",
        "DP": "criteria_fair-ecommerce",
        "DQ": "criteria_made_in_germany-ecommerce",
        "DR": "criteria_careful_use_of_resources-ecommerce",
        "DS": "criteria_pullutants_reduced_production-ecommerce",
        "DT": "short_description-ecommerce",
        "DU": null,
        "DV": "active-lade",
        "DW": "active-lmde",
        "DX": "active-mydk",
        "DY": "active-myth",
        "DZ": "active-zade",
        "EA": "active-amde",
        "EB": "active-gohk",
        "EC": "active-gode",
        "ED": null
    },
    "2": {
        "A": "4053201059663",
        "B": "BA-31017590004-100-36",
        "C": "ba",
        "D": 1058,
        "E": "nos",
        "F": "unisex",
        "G": "adult",
        "H": "care_products",
        "I": "BA-31017590004",
        "J": "BA-31017590004-100",
        "K": "Premium FuÃŸbett BAMA Balance Comfort",
        "L": "Premium FuÃŸbett BAMA Balance Comfort",
        "M": null,
        "N": "footbed_insole",
        "O": "brown",
        "P": "brown",
        "Q": 36,
        "R": 36,
        "S": "eu_size",
        "T": "19.95",
        "U": "21.95",
        "V": "2.28",
        "W": "21.95",
        "X": "Das Bama FuÃŸbett Balance Comfort bietet den ganzen Tag spÃ¼rbar \nverbesserten Komfort, UnterstÃ¼tzung und DÃ¤mpfung fÃ¼r Ihre FÃ¼ÃŸe. Das anatomisch geformte FuÃŸbett mit integrierter Fersenschale, FuÃŸgewÃ¶lbe und MittelfuÃŸstÃ¼tze verbessert Halt und StabilitÃ¤t im Schuh. Die zweilagige Konstruktion absorbiert effektiv StÃ¶ÃŸe und reduziert den Druck bei jedem Schritt. Der weiche Gel-Einsatz schafft durch ein spezielles Luftkammersystem eine schonendere Trittunterlage, wodurch Schmerzen im sensiblen Fersen- und Ballenbereich spÃ¼rbar vermindert werden. Die verbesserte StoÃŸabsorption mindert einen groÃŸen Teil der Belastung und Druck. So werden Ihre FÃ¼ÃŸe sowohl geschont als auch entlastet. Der angenehme, feuchtigkeitsaufnehmende Veloursbezug und die Perforationen ermÃ¶glichen den Transport von Luft und Feuchtigkeit.",
        "Y": "Das premium FuÃŸbett Balance Comfort von Bama fÃ¼r spÃ¼rbar verbesserten Tragekomfort.",
        "Z": "Die Air Cushion Technologie im Gel der Einlegesohle bildet eine schonende und Schmerz mindernde Trittunterlage.",
        "AA": "Das anatomisch geformte FuÃŸbett mit integrierter Fersenschale, FuÃŸgewÃ¶lbe MittelfuÃŸstÃ¼tze verbessert Halt und StabilitÃ¤t",
        "AB": "Die zweilagige Konstruktion der Sohle absorbiert effektiv StÃ¶ÃŸe und reduziert den Druck bei jedem Schritt.",
        "AC": "Der angenehme, feuchtigkeitsaufnehmende Velourbezug & die Perforation ermÃ¶glichen den Transport von Luft & Feuchtigkeit",
        "AD": "Gel-Polsterung, Schuheinlage Gesundheit, Weiche Sohle, Insoles, Sneaker, Schuhe, SchweiÃŸ, FÃ¼ÃŸe, FuÃŸbett, Aktivkohle, Kohle, Luftkammersystem, Herren, Damen, TrittdÃ¤mpfung, Einlagesohlen, Schuheinlagen",
        "AE": "ba/4053201059663_001.jpeg",
        "AF": "ba/4053201059663_001.jpeg",
        "AG": "ba/4053201059663_040.jpeg",
        "AH": "ba/4053201059663_041.jpeg",
        "AI": "ba/4053201059663_042.jpeg",
        "AJ": "ba/4053201059663_043.jpeg",
        "AK": "ba/4053201059663_044.jpeg",
        "AL": "ba/4053201059663_045.jpeg",
        "AM": null,
        "AN": null,
        "AO": null,
        "AP": null,
        "AQ": null,
        "AR": null,
        "AS": null,
        "AT": null,
        "AU": null,
        "AV": null,
        "AW": null,
        "AX": null,
        "AY": null,
        "AZ": null,
        "BA": null,
        "BB": null,
        "BC": null,
        "BD": null,
        "BE": null,
        "BF": "Obermaterial: 100% Microvelours; Innenmaterial: 100% Gel",
        "BG": "100% Microvelours",
        "BH": "100% Gel",
        "BI": "Inhaltsstoffe: Microvelours, Gel",
        "BJ": "hand_wash",
        "BK": "no",
        "BL": "no",
        "BM": "no",
        "BN": "no",
        "BO": "Â breathable,Â ergonomic,Â supportive,stabilizing,cushioning,anti_shock",
        "BP": "carton_box",
        "BQ": "Â no",
        "BR": "air_cushion,footbed",
        "BS": null,
        "BT": null,
        "BU": null,
        "BV": "3.2",
        "BW": "CENTIMETER",
        "BX": "10.9",
        "BY": "CENTIMETER",
        "BZ": "uni",
        "CA": null,
        "CB": null,
        "CC": null,
        "CD": null,
        "CE": null,
        "CF": "China",
        "CG": "31017590004-360",
        "CH": 19,
        "CI": null,
        "CJ": "CENTIMETER",
        "CK": null,
        "CL": "CENTIMETER",
        "CM": null,
        "CN": "CENTIMETER",
        "CO": "0.155",
        "CP": "Kilogramm",
        "CQ": "640690509000",
        "CR": "reference_size",
        "CS": "reference_size",
        "CT": "reference_size",
        "CU": "reference_size",
        "CV": "reference_size",
        "CW": "reference_size",
        "CX": "reference_size",
        "CY": "reference_size",
        "CZ": "reference_size",
        "DA": "reference_size",
        "DB": "reference_size",
        "DC": 1,
        "DD": "reference_size",
        "DE": "reference_size",
        "DF": "reference_size",
        "DG": "reference_size",
        "DH": "reference_size",
        "DI": "reference_size",
        "DJ": null,
        "DK": null,
        "DL": null,
        "DM": null,
        "DN": null,
        "DO": null,
        "DP": null,
        "DQ": null,
        "DR": null,
        "DS": null,
        "DT": null,
        "DU": null,
        "DV": 1,
        "DW": 1,
        "DX": 1,
        "DY": 1,
        "DZ": 1,
        "EA": 1,
        "EB": "reference_size",
        "EC": "reference_size",
        "ED": null
    },

}
```

]

I am trying to convert its present state to follow the below structure like template

```
{
  "code": "model-biker-jacket-leather",
  "family": "clothing",
  "family_variant": "clothing_material_size",
  "parent": "model-biker-jacket",
  "categories": [
    "summer_collection"
  ],
  "values": {
    "color": [
      {
        "locale": null,
        "scope": null,
        "data": "antique_white"
      }
    ],
    "material": [
      {
        "locale": null,
        "scope": null,
        "data": "leather"
      }
    ],
    "variation_name": [
      {
        "locale": "en_US",
        "scope": null,
        "data": "Biker jacket leather"
      }
    ],
    "name": [
      {
        "locale": "en_US",
        "scope": null,
        "data": "Biker jacket"
      }
    ],
    "collection": [
      {
        "locale": null,
        "scope": null,
        "data": [
          "summer_2017"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "description": [
      {
        "locale": "en_US",
        "scope": "ecommerce",
        "data": "Biker jacket"
      }
    ]
  },
  "associations": {
    "PACK": {
      "products": [
        "sunglass"
      ],
      "product_models": [],
      "groups": []
    }
  },
  "quantified_associations": {
    "PRODUCT_SET": {
      "products": [
        {
          "identifier": "top",
          "quantity": 2
        },
        {
          "identifier": "cap",
          "quantity": 1
        }
      ],
      "product_models": [
        {
          "code": "model-biker-jacket-leather",
          "quantity": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "created": "2017-10-02T15:03:55+02:00",
  "updated": "2017-10-02T15:03:55+02:00"
}
```

all values within this template I want to look like exist in my initial outputted json data

and the code I have used to derive my initial json output is

```
$data = array(1,$wole->toArray(null,true,true,true)); 
   

header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $json = json_encode(
        $data,
   
    JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE
);
```

and this is the closest I have been able to come to getting my swerved columns with their values

```
foreach ($data['1'] as $key => $value) {
 
   echo json_encode(
         $value['I'],
        JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE
);
```

problem with this is, im having to write a code for each column I want to output, which I really think is not the most straight forward way.

Please how can I do this?

Comment: Please: 1) Don't just ask us to write the code for you. While we're glad to help when you're stuck, you're still expected to make an effort of your own. 2) Provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with the emphasis on *minimal* here, as you've just dumped a large JSON on us, that seemingly has nothing to do with your desired result.

Comment: thanks ill adjust what iv written to show what I have tried

Comment: the first json file is a complete list of possible data, while the desired structure im looking to implement has a selected few based on my original output

Comment: Well, if you only want to select some specific columns, you have to write them explicitly somewhere in the code. You could simplify it by defining an array that contains the keys you want and then when you iterate, you could use `in_array` to check if the current key is on that list.

Comment: thank you @El_Vanja